# Does my new Helios 44m have fungus?

Tags: lens, fungus

I just bought a new Zenit 122 camera with helios 44m-6 lens. The lens has something inside and I'm afraid if it's fungus and could infect my other lenses[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "infect my other lenses" - there is nothing infectious in fungus, it's spores are flying everywhere already. It will never grow unless you store your lenses in moist conditions and never use them.

Answer (score 2):

That does not look like typical fungus... it just looks to be quite dusty

Comment: Plus some hair or fabric/carpet fibers.